# how can display html page in action

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

my project structure :

[image]

RouteConfig :

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h3>hi</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Home Controller :

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

`WebApi` is startup project.

how can display `index.html` in `Index` action or replace `Index view` with `index.html`.

Comment: Why not copy the content of index.html to index.cshtml view ?

Comment: i am going to test it

Comment: It's impossible maybe.

Answer (score 0):

The files are in different profects, you can´t do it at this way.

Why you dont use the home/index action and views/home/index.cshtml to put your index.html content?

Or you can make a redirect to index.html URL on home/index action.

Answer (score 0):

By default, your controller action will return Index.cshtml view instead of Index.html page. If you want to do redirection pointed at Index.html on WebClient project, modify your Index action method inside controller like this (set your WebClient's full address path, because tidle sign to replace site root path doesn't work at this case):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Redirect("http://ServerAddressOrName:Port/WebClient/Index.html");
    }
}
```

Afterwards, you need to build both projects then assign your WebApi and WebClient to different sites, since it is impossible to combine them with different Web.config content.